# Binding Silverlight controls collection to Grid - possible or not?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, binding

I'm a bit new to Silverlight and now I'm developing a map app. I have a collection of custom controls (map markers, POIs, etc). Every control has a property "Location" of the type Point, where `Location.X` means `Canvas.Left` of the control, `Location.Y`means `Canvas.Top` of the control.

I'm trying to refactor my interface to MVVM pattern. I want to do something like this:

1. Say my controls are in Canvas. I want to have something like:

   `<Canvas DataContext="{StaticResource myModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding controlsCollection}">`

   `<Canvas.ItemTemplate> ... </Canvas.ItemTemplate>`

   `</Canvas>`
2. In my custom control I want to have something like:

   `<myCustomControl DataContext="{StaticResource myControlModel}" Canvas.Left="{Binding Location.X}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Location.Y}" />`

Is it possible? Maybe there's a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after all times of googling, asking and reading, here I found a solution:

1. There should be a model implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface. DependencyProperties are not necessary. Here's an example:

   ```
   public class MyItemModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
       ...
       //

       private Point _location;
       public Point Location
       {
           get { return Location; }
           set { _location = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Location"); }
       }

       // any other fields
       ...
       //
   }
   ```
2. Then, say we have a model with a collection of MyItemModels:

   ```
   public class MyModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
       ...
       //

       private ObservableCollection<MyItemModel> _myCollection;
       public ObservableCollection<MyItemModel> MyCollection
       {
           get { return _myCollection; }
           set { _myCollection = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("MyCollection"); }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Then, in XAML, we should use ItemsControl like this:

   ```
   <ItemsControl x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{StaticResource model}"
               ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
       <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <Canvas x:Name="host"/>
           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
       </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <Grid x:Name="item" Background="Transparent">
                   <Grid.RenderTransform>
                       <TranslateTransform X="{Binding Location.X}" Y="{Binding Location.Y}"/>
                   </Grid.RenderTransform>

                   // other stuff here
                   ...
                   //

               </Grid>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

   </ItemsControl>
   ```

Works like a charm :) Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I would think it is possible to use the ItemsControl control for this.

Let's say you create a holder-control that holds the position of the control + more info that you choose.
I call it "ControlDefinition.cs":

```
public class ControlDefinition : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TopProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Top", typeof(Double), typeof(ControlDefinition), new PropertyMetadata(0d));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LeftProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Left", typeof(Double), typeof(ControlDefinition), new PropertyMetadata(0d));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Model", typeof(Object), typeof(ControlDefinition), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public Double Top
    {
        get { return (Double)GetValue(TopProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TopProperty, value);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Top");
        }
    }
    public Double Left
    {
        get { return (Double)GetValue(LeftProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(LeftProperty, value);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Left");
        }
    }
    public Object Model
    {
        get { return (Object)GetValue(ModelProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ModelProperty, value);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Model");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String aPropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(aPropertyName));
    }
}
```

Then, in my MODEL (ViewModel.cs), I create an ObservableCollection of this class:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ControlsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Controls", typeof(ObservableCollection<ControlDefinition>), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));
public new ObservableCollection<ControlDefinition> Controls
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<ControlDefinition>)GetValue(ControlsProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(ControlsProperty, value);
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Controls");
    }
}
```

Then, in the same MODEL, I initialize the collection and adds 4 dummy controls:

```
this.Controls = new ObservableCollection<ControlDefinition>();
this.Controls.Add(new ControlDefinition() { Top = 10, Left = 10, Model = "One" });
this.Controls.Add(new ControlDefinition() { Top = 50, Left = 10, Model = "Two" });
this.Controls.Add(new ControlDefinition() { Top = 90, Left = 10, Model = "Three" });
```

And I would have my VIEW (View.xaml) something like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Controls}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Background="Beige" IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Model, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Top, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=Left, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

NOTE that I show a "TextBlock" control inside my "DataTemplate", in lack of your control.
And I show the "Model" property (which I have defined as "String") in the TextBlock's "Text" property. You can assign the "Model" property to your control's "DataContext" property as in your example.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but there must be something vary in silverlight. For example, in Canvas that is ItemPanelTemplate property IsItemsHost is missing, so as for ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle (no ItemContainerStyle property in ItemsControl at all).

I tried to remove missing code but it isn't worked - my ItemsControl displays only one control.

I also tried writing only ItemTemplate section and I got all items aligned vertically as they are in StackPanel.